# Azure VM resize in same physical cluster

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-vm-templates

I am trying to resize an Azure VM using command line. The VM size is listed in the list of sizes that this VM can be resized to. But when I try to resize this VM I am unable to do because of this error

> Unable to resize the VM 'XYZ' because the requested size Standard_F4s
>   is not available in the current hardware cluster.

Is there a way we can get the information beforehand to which all sizes this VM can be resized to successfully?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Get-AzureRmVmSize` to check VM size. The sample below does not only check hardware cluster but also disk, region availability to make sure you can resize your VM.

```
$rg = "azuredev-rg"
$vmName = "A0VM"
Get-AzureRmVMSize -ResourceGroupName $rg -VMName $vmName
```

Note that the output **is dependent on the VM status running**. You can change your existing VM size when it is running. However, **not all available sizes are listed if that VM is running**. It means some designated sizes require stopping VM to be deallocated first (due to different hardware cluster)

For defensive programming, below sample would be a consideration to check VM status before performing resizing

```
$vm = (Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $vmName -Status).Statuses
$vm.DisplayStatus
```

The output shows you

```
Provisioning succeeded
VM running
```

Below is the sample PowerShell script to check VM status then perform resizing

```
$rg = "azuredev-rg"
$vmName = "A0VM"
$newSize = "Standard_B1s"

$vm = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $vmName
$vmS = Get-AzureRmVMSize -ResourceGroupName $rg -VMName $vmName

if ($vmS.Name -contains $newSize) 
{
    Write-Output "This size is supported"
    $vm.HardwareProfile.VmSize = $newSize
    Update-AzureRmVM -VM $vm -ResourceGroupName $rg
    Write-Output "The VM size is being updated"
}

else
{
    while($vmStatus.DisplayStatus -contains "VM running")
    {
        $vmStatus = (Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $vmName -Status).Statuses
        Write-Output $vmStatus
        Write-Output "VM is being stopped"
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
    }
    Stop-AzureRmVM -Name $vmName -ResourceGroupName $rg -Force
    $vm.HardwareProfile.VmSize = $newSize
    Update-AzureRmVM -VM $vm -ResourceGroupName $rg
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I needed !!! The corresponding REST API is 
     https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription-d>/resourceGroups/<resource-group-name>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/<vm-name>/vmSizes?api-version=2017-12-01

Comment: how do you stop VM in the while loop?

Answer (score 0):

Agree with [Thuan Ng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9330826/thuan-ng).

If your VM(s) are deployed using the Resource Manager (ARM) deployment model and you need to change to a size which requires different hardware then you can resize VMs by **first stopping** your VM, selecting a new VM size and then **restarting** the VM.

> Is there a way we can get the information beforehand to which all
>   sizes this VM can be resized to successfully?

Do you mean you want to get which all sizes in **current hardware** are available?

Based on my knowledge, it is **not** possible.

The resize operation is a simple **reboot** operation, maybe we can stop it first and resize it, then restarting the VM.

Answer (score 0):

If by command line you mean azure-cli, you can always use:

`az vm list-vm-resize-options  -g test-resourcegroup -n test-vm -o table`

As a result you'll see vm sizes you can use in `az vm resize` without the need for `deallocate`. If you'd like to check what's available in the location of your interest you can use something like:
    `az vm list-sizes -l westeurope -o table`
You can use any size listed in the output of the command above when you `az vm deallocate` this VM. If you're interested in more detail you can check [this article](https://funinit.wordpress.com/2018/03/27/resizing-vms-in-azure/).